# How do I add an i2c device to the device tree?

Tags: i2c, kernel, device-tree

I am trying to add an [mpu 9250](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13762) to the device tree of my RPi 3 A+ so that my custom driver's probe function will be called. I have followed [this documentation about the Raspberry Pi device tree](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md) and [this documentation describing the required properties for binding the mpu9250](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/iio/imu/inv_mpu6050.txt). Here is what I have so far:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2708";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&i2c1>;
        __overlay__ {
            status = "okay";
            mpu9250@68 {
                compatible = "invensense,mpu9250";
                reg = <0x68>;
                interrupt-parent = <&gpio3>;
                interrupts = <21 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING>;
                status = "okay";
                };
        };
    };
};
```

I build it on the target RPi 3 A+ with this command:

```
dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o mpu_9250.dtbo mpu_9250.dts
```

and here is the result:

```
Error: mpu_9250.dts:19.25-26 syntax error
FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree
```

I think it is complaining about `IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING`. When I change `IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING` to a `1` then build, I get:

```
mpu_9250.dtbo: Warning (reg_format): "reg" property in /fragment@0/__overlay__/mpu9250@68 has invalid length (4 bytes) (#address-cells == 2, #size-cells == 1)
mpu_9250.dtbo: Warning (unit_address_vs_reg): Node /fragment@0 has a unit name, but no reg property
mpu_9250.dtbo: Warning (pci_device_reg): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
mpu_9250.dtbo: Warning (pci_device_bus_num): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
mpu_9250.dtbo: Warning (simple_bus_reg): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
mpu_9250.dtbo: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #address-cells value for /fragment@0/__overlay__/mpu9250@68
mpu_9250.dtbo: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): Relying on default #size-cells value for /fragment@0/__overlay__/mpu9250@68
dtc: livetree.c:521: get_node_by_phandle: Assertion `(phandle != 0) && (phandle != -1)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How do I fix these issues? What resources should I turn to?

I know that a driver already exists for the device, allowing access to it thru sysfs, and about i2c-dev but they don't suit my purposes.

Thanks

Comment: It's probably better to ask the same question at: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewforum.php?f=107 where the folks from RPF/RPTL who know about device tree hang out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Hex number of the IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING.

interrupts = <21 0x1>;

Comment: The OP already tried to replace `IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING` by `1`.